# Creating training set of strike and dip data (structural geology) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, image-classification, deep-learning

I have been using ArcGIS Pro for the first time, and am attempting to create a training set of strike and dip data (structural geology.) I have created the polygons, after creating a new classification schema, but the files are not available for import when I got to the classification wizard. I am confused as to where I may have made a misstep, or where the program is getting confused.

For what it's worth, I have followed the Esri walkthroughs on a few deep learning/image classification projects and I think I was authentic to their directions.

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you performed?